# Имя класса начинается со второго элемента массива

Tags: php

Почему имя класса блока начинается с **bed?**

По идее должно начинаться с **home.**
Вроде все сделал правильно, не могу понять где косяк.

```js
$number = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
];

$class = [             
  "home",
  "bed",
  "table"
];

$i = 0;

foreach($number as $items) {

 ++$i;
 echo "<article class ='$class[$i]'>$items</article>" ; 

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это из-за инкремента `++$i`. На первой же итерации цикла он становится равным единице, после чего только выводится `echo`. Нужно просто переместить `++$i` после `echo`

```
$number = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
];

$class = [             
  "home",
  "bed",
  "table"
];

$i = 0;

foreach($number as $items) {

 echo "<article class ='$class[$i]'>$items</article>" ; // сначала echo
 ++$i; // и только потом инкремент

};
```

Comment: Классно, го обмен лайками =)